# How to auto-close the terminal after exit debugging in QT Creator?

Tags: ide, qt-creator

In QT Creator, there is an annoying issue:

When debugging a console program, a terminal window will show, and even if the debugging session has terminated, the dead terminal window is still there with a message: "Press <RETURN> to close this window...".

If debugging a program many times, the number of dead terminal windows will be too many.

Is there a way to automatically close the terminal window after exiting the debugging session?

Comment: I tried killing the parent process (the Creator process stub) with `::kill(::getppid(), SIGKILL)` as well as `SIGTERM`, but somehow the process manages to catch that and reports a crash. With the effect that I'm not even able to close the terminal using `Enter`.